# How to import bootstrap via global .scss file instead of main.js in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass

Currently I am importing bootstrap as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

import 'bootstrap'; // I want to transfer this
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; // and this

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Is there a way to transfer it on a global scss file configures as follows? :
vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `
            @import "@/style/main.scss";
        `,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

src/style/main.scss

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

body {
  background-color: #333;
}
```

Above `@import` example does not work and causes an error "Can't resolve path".

The reason for needing this is to eliminate having to use `!important` withing my `main.scss` just to override bootstrap styles. It seems that `main.scss` is executed before the bootstrap import on `main.js`.

Comment: I would **not** recommend adding all of bootstrap to `prependData`, as it will import the entire bootstrap CSS into every single component of yours that uses a `<style lang="scss">` tag. You should remove the bootstrap `CSS` import in `main.js` and import your `SCSS` file instead, if you want to use `SCSS`.

Comment: @Hiws, I need to clarify. Thanks for the help btw. I should remove the `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'` from main.js? and add `import './style/main.scss' in main.js? Is that what you mean?

Comment: That's what i mean, yes. Right now you're importing Bootstrap twice. Once in `main.js` and once in `main.scss`. There's a good chance this can conflict based on the loading order. You might also need the appropriate SCSS loaders if you don't have them added to your project yet.

Comment: @Hiws But I don't need to import my `scss` file from `main.js` because i already set up my `vue.config.js`